# In c# , Why QuartzApp Scheduler not working on deployment server, but perfect working in local server

Tags: c#, quartz.net

CallForImportProperties.cs

```
public class CallForImportProperties : IJob
{    
    public static readonly string dailySchedulerRunTime = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DailySchedulerRunTimestatus"].ToString();
    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        var task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (dailySchedulerRunTime.Equals("ON"))
            {
                try
                {
                    method();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
        });
       await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("HelloJob is executing.");
    }
```

Scheduler.CS

```
public class Scheduler
{
    
    public static void Start()
    {
       
        string dailySchedulerRunTime = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DailySchedulerRunTime"].ToString();
       

        IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler().Result;

  
        IJobDetail jobImportProperties = JobBuilder.Create<CallForImportProperties>().Build();
        ITrigger triggerImportProperties = TriggerBuilder.Create()
           .ForJob(jobImportProperties)
           .WithCronSchedule(dailySchedulerRunTime)
           .Build();
        scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobImportProperties, triggerImportProperties);
        #endregion

        scheduler.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Can you please give us a bit more information? What issue are you running into? What have you tried to solve it? Can you also edit your post and format your code so it's readable for us?

Comment: Just to note - you have an empty catch block, so you are just swallowing exceptions, and the exceptions are almost certainly telling you exactly why it's failing in production. I would imagine if you add some logging to your solution you will be able to find the answer out yourself (or, at least, give us the information required to help you).

Comment: I also try that thing but not raise any exception in Deployment site, so i am not understand what doing exectly.

Comment: Did you turn on "Always On" option on IIS web server? https://newbedev.com/quartz-net-scheduler-doesn-t-fire-jobs-triggers-once-deployed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to Use **InTimeZone()** in your method **TriggerBuilder.Create()**

```
ITrigger triggerImportProperties = TriggerBuilder.Create()
           .ForJob(jobImportProperties)
           .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule
           (s=>
            s.WithIntervalInHours(Convert.ToInt32(dailySchedulerRunTime))
           .OnEveryDay()
           .InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.Local))
           .Build();
```

let me know if any concern. I guess it will work. Because, it is working for me.

Thanks.